401 Unauthenticated error while using laravel sanctum
I'm using laravel framework version 8.54 and sanctum version 2.15

Creating apis
Login and get User
On local environment it works fine but on production it return 401 error


Configurations
Added HasApiTokens in Customers model with using use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
Creating access tokens

 public function customerLogin(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
         'email' => 'required|email',
         'password' => 'required|string',
      ]);
     $customer = Customer::where('email', $request->email)->first();
     if ($customer && Hash::check($request->password, $customer->password)) {
         $token = $customer->createToken('Api Token for the customer')->plainTextToken;
         return response()->json(['success' => true,'token' => $token]);
       }
     return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Email or Password is wrong']);
     }



getting customer

  public function AuthenticatedCustomer(){
        return response()->json(['customer' => Auth::user()]);
    }


auth.php

'guards' => [
    'customer' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
         'provider' => 'customers'
       ],
     ],
    'providers' => [
            'customers' => [
                    'driver' => 'eloquent',
                    'model' => App\Models\Customer::class,
             ]
    ]


Routes

 Route::post('/login',[CustomerController::class,'customerLogin']);
 Route::get('/customer',[CustomerController::class,'AuthenticatedCustomer'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');


Help me to resolve this error of 401

Problem on my side is that request strips the authorization from headers

Answer is too brief and not useful for the community.
